# Implement two lists in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS. I want to implement two tables. First one will have list of possible items to select. Second one can be empty. I will have 4 buttons in between the two tables as "move this item left", "move all to left", "move all to right" and "move this to right".

Which component should i use to implement this?

Regards,

Anandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ItemSelector` plugin:

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html